# ListActivity TwoLineListItem Alternative

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I notice that TwoLineListItem is deprecated as of API 17. What is the alternative to this if I am setting up a ListActivity adapter as follows?:

```
ArrayAdapter<File> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<File>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,filesArrayList){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                final TwoLineListItem row;
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
                }else{
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)convertView;
                }
                row.getText1().setText(filesArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
                row.getText2().setText2(filesArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
                return row;
            }

        };
```

Comment: You can write your own `View` that has two text `View`s in it with the appropriate styling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply cut and paste the TwoLineListItem source code into a layout of your own:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(Notice I changed the ids for consistency.)

Now use a ViewHolder that keeps references to both TextViews:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        // You should fetch the LayoutInflater once in your constructor
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_2, null);

        // Initialize ViewHolder here
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    File file = filesArrayList.get(position);
    holder.text1.setText(file.getTitle());
    holder.text2.setText2(file.getDescription());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I did it:

> ```
>     mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, mListItems)
>     {
>         @Override
>         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
>         {
>             View row;
>             if(convertView == null)
>             {
>                 row = (View)mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, null);
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 row = (View)convertView;
>             }
>             TextView v = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
>             v.setText(mListItems[position]);
>             v = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
>             v.setText(mListSubItems[position]);
>             return row;
>         }
>     };
> ```

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.runsListView);
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

Comment: Good, except here is no need for the casts `row = (View) ...` since inflate() and convertView are already View's.

Answer (score 0):

First is deprecated, so that is not too bad for you. Because it will be supported for ever. ;)

***[If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)***

You are free to use any layout! **Just add some background to respond** the selected state if you are using a  mode selection, like:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Comment: Deprecation is like to say that something should not be used, and in future may not work as expected. So why take the risk if you know?